# Cross database ownership chaining with Master Data Services DB

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

We are using cross database ownership chaining with several databases. Works fine, since the owner of all objects involved is dbo.

We now have to include data from Master Data Services (MDS). MDS uses the mdm user as object owner per default. Is there a way - by using certificates or something - to still use ownership chaining with the MDS database while keeping the mdm owner?

Comment: My current workaround is: select data using a multi-statement function WITH EXECUTE AS 'dbo' (give access to the data through a view that is permissioned for users) and SET TRUSTWORTHY ON for all databases involved including the MDS database.